# Не работает на больших числах. Python. Задача с отображением времени

Tags: python, математика

Функция принимает число секунд и должна вернуть время в формате "лет, дней, часов, минут, секунд." Вот ссылка на задачу с CodeWars: https://www.codewars.com/kata/52742f58faf5485cae000b9a
Код по очереди проверяет на положительность остаток от деления исходного числа на количество секунд соответственно в году, дне, месяце и т.д. Например сначала ищется остаток от деления числа на количество секунд в году, находится целое количество лет, от исходного числа отнимается количество секунд в этом числе лет, и дальше переходит к следующей проверке.

```
# Your task in order to complete this Kata is to write a function which 
#formats a duration,
# given as a number of seconds, in a human-friendly way.
#
#The function must accept a non-negative integer. If it is zero, it just  
#"now".
# Otherwise, the duration is expressed as a combination of years, days, 
#hours, minutes and seconds.
#
# It is much easier to understand with an example:
#
# format_duration(62)    # returns "1 minute and 2 seconds"
# format_duration(3662)  # returns "1 hour, 1 minute and 2 seconds"
#
# 1 minute = 60 sec
# 1 hour = 3600 sec
# 1 day = 86400 sec
# 1 year = 31536000 sec


def format_duration(s):
    string = ""
    a = []
    y = 0
    d = 0
    h = 0
    m = 0
    sec = 0
    if s <= 0:
        return "now"
    if s % 31536000 > 0:
        y += int((s - s % 31536000) / 31536000)
        s -= int(y) * 31536000
        if y != 0:
            a.append(y)
            if y == 1:
                a.append(" year, ")
            else:
                a.append(" years, ")
    if s & 86400 > 0:
        d += int((s - s % 86400) / 86400)
        s -= int(d) * 86400
        if d != 0:
            a.append(d)
            if d == 1:
                a.append(" day, ")
            else:
                a.append(" days, ")
    if s & 3600 > 0:
        h += int((s - s % 3600) / 3600)
        s -= int(h) * 3600
        if h != 0:
            a.append(h)
            if h == 1:
                a.append(" hour, ")
            else:
                a.append(" hours, ")
    if s & 60 > 0:
        m += int((s - s % 60) / 60)
        s -= int(m) * 60
        if m != 0:
            a.append(m)
            if m == 1:
                a.append(" minute, ")
            else:
                a.append(" minutes, ")
    if s < 60:
        sec += s
        if sec != 0:
            a.append(sec)
            if sec == 1:
                a.append(" second, ")
            else:
                a.append(" seconds, ")
    if len(a) > 2:
        a[-3] = a[-3][:-2]
        a.insert(-2, " and ")
    for i in a:
        string += str(i)
    return string[:-2]


print(format_duration(253374061))
```

Не работает конкретно на числе 253374061.
Насколько я понял, пропускается третий этап проверки (на кол-во часов). Компьютер считает, что остаток отделения равен 0, хотя это не так (я проверял).
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Компьютер не считает, что остаток равен 0, поскольку в том месте он вычисляет не остаток, а совсем другое.

Замените везде оператор `&` (откуда он взялся и зачем?) на `%`.